# Main plugin with child plugins - WP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to WordPress but I would like to create a plugin which lists all the plugins settings of the custom plugins I'm creating, so I don't have to go in each and every plugin.

In the main plugin I have this:

```
if (!function_exists('get_plugins'))
    require_once (ABSPATH."wp-admin/includes/plugin.php");
    $all_plugins = get_plugins();
    foreach($all_plugins as $plugin_key => $plugin_data){   
        if (strpos(strtolower($plugin_data['Name']),'prefix') !== false) { 
            //skip this one as this is the main plugin and we do not need to display any thing
            if (strpos(strtolower($plugin_data['Name']),'plugins') === false) {
                 if (is_plugin_active($plugin_key)) {                       
                     require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/'.$plugin_key);
                     $plugin_class_name =  preg_replace('/\s+/','', str_replace("'", "", ucwords($plugin_data['Name'])));

                     $class_handler = new $plugin_class_name();  
                     ?>
                     <div id="sec-<?php echo $plugin_key ?>" class="section">
                         <div class="section-header">
                             <h3><?php echo $plugin_data['Name']?></h3>
                         </div>
                         <div class="section-content">
                            <?php $class_handler->show_settings() ?>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <?php
                 }
            }
        }
    }
```

What the above snippet does is get all the plugins with the prefix I have. This works fine and even the bit : `$class_handler->show_settings()` as the display works just fine, but I'm having issue with en queuing styles and JS.. so this is the code in the child plugin:

```
function __construct(){
    if ( !function_exists( 'add_action' ) ) {
        echo "This page cannot be called directly.";
        exit;
    }   
    if(preg_match('#' . basename(__FILE__) . '#', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) { die('You are not allowed to call this page directly.'); }

    if(is_admin()){
        //call be scripts
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'add_be_script'));
    } else{
        //call frontend scripts
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',  array($this, 'add_fe_script'));
    }
}
function add_be_script(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );   
}
```

but the color picker is not being included in the styles as the function `add_be_script()` is not being called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wp_enqueue_scripts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) only enqueue css and js to the front

to add your css/js file in back office, use:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'add_be_script');
```

This will call add_be_script() in the back office head.

edit, andy answer alternative is better:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_be_script');
```

Comment: Or there's `admin_enqueue_scripts`